# is it possible set pendingtransition while starting external intent like camera

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible like in topic, I mean start camera intent and before opening that view set screen not to see rotating screen effectc? I was trying to use `overridePendingTransition` after `startingActivityForResult`, I tried also to put this `overriDePendingTransition` while calling `onPause` and `OnResume`. Somehow camera uses own animation. I would like to disable that animation. Is is possible? This effect doesn't affect in android 2.3.x. Does it might have connection with touchWiz?

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR**

As of KitKat 4.4.2 this still does not seem possible. Tested with AOSP phone app, Nexus 5 experience Phone App, Maps, AOSP Browser and Chrome.

(I would have put this in a comment, not enough rep yet. It's still an answer per-say, though not a solution to the problem)

Only thing I can say about why it's not possible is:

- If you could force a transaction on the "external" intent through
  your own app code, you would be basically *injecting your animation
  into another publisher's app*, which would be a **MAJOR design flaw**
  in the Android framework.

My guess is this will never be possible unless the OS manages such transactions in a bullet-proof way to both ends. Some AOSP branded-builds and custom Launchers can change **default** animations for ALL activity starts/resumes though (or even use no animations at all).

Comment: I believe it could be possible with xposed apk which makes miracles but I need somehow without root pemrissions :)

Comment: It seems you could, but then again you would be diluting Android's application vs system domain, and it's a confusing mix already. I see it like this: you got a nice and open framework (and I mean full-source open, nothing like iOS) which allows administrator rights and whatnot to enable the power-user. Anything that manipulates app internals cannot fall in the freedom concept, it's cut-throat hacking. There should be no need for that - if apps want to be nice OR performance effective, it's up to the publisher to optimize his app using the SDK, not the system (or an enabled external service)..